# Reading JSON data from a url using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to read data from this link http://starlord.hackerearth.com/gamesext.
I went through this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON and was able to obtain data from https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/oojs/json/superheroes.json.
Trying similar approach for getting data from http://starlord.hackerearth.com/gamesext is not working for me.
This is how I tried:

```
var requestURL = 'http://starlord.hackerearth.com/gamesext';
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', requestURL);
    request.responseType = 'json';
    request.send();
    request.onload = function() {
    var games = request.response;
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "for check";//para is a paragraph id
    fun1(games);
    }
    function fun1(jsonObj){
        //getting first title
        document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = jsonObj[0]["title"];
    }
```

I would want to know is that data in JSON and how to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `JSON.parse()` method:

```
function fun1(jsonObj){
    //getting first title
    jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = jsonObj[0]["title"];
}
```

This will turn valid JSON into a javascript object that can be accessed as you are trying to do below.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly fine for me:

```
var requestURL = 'http://starlord.hackerearth.com/gamesext';
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhttp.response[0].title)  # LittleBigPlanet PS Vita
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", requestURL);
xhttp.responseType = 'json';
xhttp.send();
```

Give it a try!

Comment: Hey Arnoux. Can the problem be caused due to large data size or due to lots of comment in the script section of html document? I removed all the comments and now your solution and my above code both are working and giving results.

Comment: Hey Adarsh! The comments in your code will certainly not cause this. I did notice that the request to that website takes very long to bring back a result, so perhaps it only seemed to not be working? Or perhaps you had other errors in your code before? Did you see anything in the console that might give a hint? Unfortunately I can only help you debug this by seeing all your code! Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Using `fetch` this is pretty simply.

Below is an example.

```js
const url = 'https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/oojs/json/superheroes.json';

async function getData() {
  const json = await (await fetch(url)).json();
  console.log(json);
}

getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

just put `request.send();` after all the code you provided.